# How to lookup items from one dataframe in another dataframe based on a custom 'matching' function

Tags: r

I have two data frames: sold1 and sold.

They both hold data on sold house prices but from different sources. As it turns out, the data, even for the same property may not match.

I’d like to compare each element in Sold1 to Sold2 and exclude those in Sold1 that are already present (duplicated) in sold2.

The test for a ‘duplicate’ in this instance would be a combination of:

1. Sold1.price is within 10% of Sold2.price
2. Sold2.address is contained in Sold1.address
3. Sold2.dateOfSale is no earlier than Sold1.dateOfSale

Two questions:

1. Why does the 'price' field change class when accessed in a function?
2. Is there a more elegant way to do this without using apply twice (very slow on two large dataframes)?

```
sold1 <- data.frame(
  price = c(100000,150000,200000,250000,300000,400000),
  address = c("Widmore Road, Bromley", "River Quaggy Apartments", "Meadowcroft Way, Orwell, SG8","Freelands Road, Bromley","Nascot Street, London, W12","Priory Terrace, South Hampstead, NW6"),
  dateOfSale = c(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2020-02-03"),as.Date("2020-03-05"),as.Date("2020-04-06"),as.Date("2020-05-08"),as.Date("2020-06-12"))
)

sold2 <- data.frame(
  price = c(100000,150000,210000,251000,300000),
  address = c("Random Road, Bromley", "Random2 Road Apartments", "Meadowcroft Way","Freelands Road","Random street London, W12"),
  dateOfSale = c(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2020-04-03"),as.Date("2020-03-25"),as.Date("2020-04-26"),as.Date("2019-05-08"))
)

FLR_Check_Match <- function (s2, s1row) {
  checkRes = TRUE
  # Price within tolerance 
  checkRes = checkRes && as.numeric(s1row["price"]) >= as.numeric(s2["price"]) * .9 && as.numeric(s1row["price"]) <= as.numeric(s2["price"]) * 1.1
  # address close match
  checkRes = checkRes && grepl(s2["address"], s1row["address"], ignore.case = TRUE)
  # date of sale falls 7 weeks after date of sale in the sold1 (s1) data
  checkRes = checkRes && as.Date(s2["dateOfSale"]) >= as.Date(s1row["dateOfSale"])
  return(checkRes)
}

FCheck_Sold_Dups <- function(s1, s2) {
  print(class(s1["price"])) #character
  #For each element in s2, check whether there is a match to s1
  excV <- apply(s2, 1, FLR_Check_Match, s1)
  result <- any(excV)
  return(result)
}

sold1$exclude <- apply(sold1,1,FCheck_Sold_Dups,sold2)
```

Comment: Does the code work for you? When I run `sold1$exclude <- apply(sold1,1,FCheck_Sold_Dups,sold2)` it returns `s2["price"] * 0.9 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: No - that’s one of the issues. When converted using as.numeric(), that error is eliminated. I however don’t understand why the class/type of the vector changes when accessed in the function.

Comment: @ Ronak, I have amended to reflect as.numeric/as.Date. It now works but the same questions apply.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why does the 'price' field change class when accessed in a function?**

`apply` coerces dataframe to matrix.

From `?apply` :

> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix

This can also verified by the source code of `apply` :

```
apply
function (X, MARGIN, FUN, ...) 
{
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    dl <- length(dim(X))
    if (!dl) 
        stop("dim(X) must have a positive length")
    if (is.object(X)) 
        X <- if (dl == 2L) 
            as.matrix(X) # <- here
        else as.array(X)
     .....
     .....
```

Since matrix can hold data of only one type everything is changed to character. Hence, you have to coerce the data into numeric again in the function.

---

**2. Is there a more elegant way to do this without using apply twice (very slow on two large dataframes)**

We cannot really avoid comparing every row of `sold1` to `sold2` (maybe fuzzy matching/joining ?) so if you have very large data most of the answers would be slow. Here is one way which is maybe more elegant, faster and shorter. I added prefix to column names of `sold1` and `sold2` dataframes to differentiate between them.

```
library(dplyr)

names(sold1) <- paste0('sold1_', names(sold1))
names(sold2) <- paste0('sold2_', names(sold2))

tidyr::crossing(sold1, sold2) %>%
        group_by(sold1_address) %>%
                  #Check if address matches
        summarise(address_check = any(str_detect(sold1_address, stringr::regex(sold2_address, ignore_case = TRUE))), 
                  #Check if price is in range
                  price_check = any(data.table::between(sold1_price, sold2_price * .9, sold2_price * 1.1)), 
                  #Check if date is in range
                  date_check = any(sold2_dateOfSale >= sold1_dateOfSale), 
                  #if all the three conditions satisfy
                  exclude = address_check & price_check & date_check) %>%
        select(sold1_address, exclude) %>%
        left_join(sold1, by = 'sold1_address')

# sold1_address                        exclude sold1_price sold1_dateOfSale
#  <chr>                                <lgl>         <dbl> <date>          
#1 Freelands Road, Bromley              TRUE         250000 2020-04-06      
#2 Meadowcroft Way, Orwell, SG8         TRUE         200000 2020-03-05      
#3 Nascot Street, London, W12           FALSE        300000 2020-05-08      
#4 Priory Terrace, South Hampstead, NW6 FALSE        400000 2020-06-12      
#5 River Quaggy Apartments              FALSE        150000 2020-02-03      
#6 Widmore Road, Bromley                FALSE        100000 2020-01-01
```

Note that I have created 3 separate columns `address_check`, `price_check` and `date_check` for clarity and keep each condition separate, they are not necessarily needed and we can combine those conditions into one if required.

Comment: That's interesting. Couldn't make it work though. Getting error Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Column `sold1_address` doesn't exist. 'summarise' seems to result in a single row table for some reason.

Comment: That's strange. It works for me though based on the data you provided. Did you rename the columns for `sold1` and `sold2` using the code at the top of my post? `names(sold1) <- paste0('sold1_', names(sold1))` and `names(sold2) <- paste0('sold2_', names(sold2))`

Comment: Yes, the result after 'summarise' is: address_check price_check date_check exclude          TRUE        TRUE       TRUE    TRUE. The other columns have disappeared as if the groupings didn't apply. However the result after 'group_by' does specify '# Groups:   sold1_address [6]'.

Comment: Do you have `plyr` loaded as well? Can you try with `dplyr::summarise()` or restart your R session and load only `dplyr`.

Comment: Good catch - that fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to take longer to run even though it looks neater. I'm wondering whether there is a vectorised solution that could apply..